# My right ALT key is not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

The left ALT key works fine, but the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does nothing. I used xev to check the button and it works. I use  it for for shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal so I want to fix this problem. thanks.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: I use English US layout and Greek.

Comment: Ok. When the Greek layout is active, Right Alt is used to access third and fourth level symbols, so combinations like <Ctrl>+<Right Alt>+T is not supposed to work. It should work, though, when English US is active, if English US means the basic US layout and not one of the variants.

Comment: It doesn't work on either of them.

Comment: With English (US), it does nothing but with English (UK), it emits alternative characters in combination with other keys character keys: ¹²³€½¾{[]}\@łe¶ŧ←↓→øþæßðđŋħł", "«»¢“”nµ,·

Comment: "English (US, intl., with dead keys)" produces similar results. Not the result you wanted but very useful if you're forever needing to type `€`!

Comment: Using "Right Alt never chooses 3rd level" you also disable the compose key, which might not be favorable to some users. But I guess, this is what changing keyboard layouts is invented for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after a lot of googling around in vain I finally managed to discover a solution.

The following solution works both when the English keyboard is selected, and when the Greek keyboard is selected. (Or any other keyboard for that matter, I suppose.)

Open "Tweaks" (aka "Gnome Tweaks") go to **Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Key to choose the 3rd level** and put a check mark on **Right Alt never chooses 3rd level**.

[image: screenshot showing Additional Layout Options dialog]

If you want to be able to achieve the same thing via the command line:

The corresponding dconf setting is `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options`, the value `'lv3:ralt_alt'` must be included in the array of values for that key.

After setting the value of this key, the tweak tool then causes the `setxkbmap` command to be invoked, with some parameters that actually do the trick on the fly, but I have not been able to figure out what those parameters are, so my guess is that if you only do `dconf` then you will need to restart your login session for the changes to take effect.

`<rant-mode>`
I suppose the problem here is that Ubuntu is a) trying to offer an impossibly oversimplified interface which yields an unusable computer out of the box, so you absolutely have to resort to things like the "Gnome Tweaks" tool, and b) this tool is offering so many incredibly arcane and entirely useless options, that the one little option that actually matters is hidden in the noise.
`</rant-mode>`

Comment: Did not solve the problem for me, is a restart needed?

Comment: Read. The. Answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. I tried to restore tweaks to default to no avail. I restarted and no change. I have a Macbook with Spanish keyboard. It was working few hours ago. The cmd doesn't work either.

Comment: @LarryGolade Are you running ubuntu on your Macbook?

Comment: Yes I do, 22.04. Now the 2 alt keys are sick. They function just like the ctrl key.

Comment: @LarryGolade ok in this case we might be looking at a difference between the mac and the PC.  I am sorry my post is not helpful to you.

Comment: I fixed the problem with settings>keyboard>alternate character keys>checked the box Right Alt. I still don't where the problem came from in the first place. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try checking response in terminal

run the command: *$* **xev** in your terminal and check whether its a hardware issue or a software

In my case the Right Alt Key was returning some additional value showing as:

XkeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92  **<----[issue]**

XFilterEvent returns : False                 **<----** *[this is fine]*

That is my keyboard was working perfectly fine.

Surprisingly I found that my text-entry language has changed to English(UK).
So when I changed it to English(US) everything started working perfectly fine.